# How Can You Change Icon Color in Jquery Mobile 1.4rc1

Tags: jquery-mobile, icons

Anyone know how to change the icon color of an icon in JQM 1.4? I'm killing the background color, disc, etc on the icon and want to change it from "black" to white bars for example. I'm not sure if the icon color can be changed through css directly anymore.

```
<a href="#main-menu" style="background-color: transparent;
box-shadow: none; border:0px; border-radius:0px; color:#fff"
           class="jqm-navmenu-link ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-none"
           data-role="button" role="button"></a>
```

Comment: In 1.4 svg is used as icons with `:after`pseudo selector. You can use ThemeRoller to create a custom theme or do changes on JQM style sheet manually. Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/LeGkm/

Comment: That doesn't actually change the color of the icon - changes the hover event of the icon. I'm digging into this a bit more and there are 2 base svg icon styles black / white - You can create more by using grunticon  - still reading

Answer (score 5):

JQuery Mobile uses SVG icons which are specified as background images of the approproate icon css definitions. The SVG image specifications are directly encoded in the urls of the background images.

So to get an icon with a different color, you can copy the css style of the appropriate icon from jquery mobile's svg css file, paste it in your own css file and adapt the fill color of the svg's polygone.

You can find further details about that at http://www.bar54.de/2014/02/jquery-mobile-change-color-of-svg-icons/

Comment: It comes with some funny errors when you use `data-iconpos="right"`, but otherwise it gets the job done.